# Text replacement in scratch-text-editor

Tags: release-loki, applications, code

How do you replace text on scratch?
Usually, text replace prompt has two text fields, but what I get is a single text field.

If I click "Replace" or "Replace all", found texts are replaced by null , meaning just erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your window is big enough to fit both text fields.

[image: When the window is big enough]
[image: When the window is too small]